# How to manage exception of ViewData in SelecList?

Tags: asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, selectlistitem

controller : `

```
public IActionResult SendReport()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listAdmin = new List<SelectListItem>();

        listAdmin.Add(
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "admin",
            Value = "0"
        });

        ViewBag.listAdmin = listAdmin;
        ViewData["listAdmin"] = listAdmin;

        return View();
    }`
```

View :`@Html.DropDownList("listAdmin",ViewData["listAdmin"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ,"Selecte")`

but Exception is "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'listAdmin'".where is m mistake?

Answer (score 1):

First,if  I use your code,I cannot reproduce the error.

And then if the data in controller is null, I will have the same error with yours:

Error message:
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'listAdmin'.

```
public IActionResult SendReport()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listAdmin = new List<SelectListItem>();

            listAdmin.Add(
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "admin",
                Value = "0"
            });
            ViewBag.listAdmin = null;
            return View();
        }
```

Next,if  I change the view like this,I will also have the same error with yours:

Error message:
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'listAdmin111'.

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("listAdmin111", ViewData["listAdmin"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecte")

</div>
```

So I think you can make sure the ViewBag and ViewData is null or not by debugging the code and right click ‘ViewBag’ and choose the ‘QuickWatch’ to see the ViewBage information.And then you can make sure if the spelling in View is the same in Controller.

Comment: I checked as you said spelling is true and also ViewBag is not null.but it show exception..do you have another idea plz?